# How to solve two sum problem using recursion?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion, vector

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
You can return the answer in any order.

Example 1:
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
.

So instead of the bruteforce method I was trying to solve this problem using recursion.It worked fine for a few test cases but it failed the test case when nums is [3,2,3] and target =6,it returns a empty array in this case. Its running into an infinite loop. How do I rectify this error?

Below is my code

```
class Solution {

public:
    void giveSolution(vector<int>& nums,int i,int target, vector<int> &v){
       
        if(nums.size()==0){
            return;
        }
        if(i==nums.size()){
            return;
        }
        if(nums[i]+nums[i+1]==target){
            v.push_back(i);
            v.push_back((i+1));
        }
        else{
            giveSolution(nums,i+1,target,v);
        }
        
        
    }

    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
         vector<int> v;
     giveSolution(nums,0,target,v);
        return v;
      
      }
};
```

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger and look at which pairs of values you are testing in the `if (nums[i] + nums[i+1] == target)`. The first time, i=0, so you test nums[0] + nums[1]. The second time, i=1, so you test nums[1] + nums[2]. The third time, i=2 so you test nums[2]+nums[3]. And then you stop. You never tested nums[0]+nums[2]. (You also made an invalid access to nums[3].)

Comment: so this problem can't be solved using recursion I suppose

Comment: It is possible, but it is nowhere near what you did, and moreover it doesn't do a better job than brute force, but with more waste of memory. So there is not a single good reason to use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The check

```
    if(i==nums.size()){
        return;
    }
```

is too late. Because already when `i == nums.size()-1` you access the vector out-of-bounds in the next line:

```
 if(nums[i]+nums[i+1]==target){
              // ^^ i+1 == nums.size()
```

This is undefined and the output of the program could be anything. Use `at` rather than `[]` to get a runtime error instead of undefined behavior.

Moreover, you are only considering adjacent elements of the input, while the tasks asks you to find any two numbers.

Comment: ok I followed on ur instruction but its still giving error

Comment: if((i+1)==nums.size()){
            return;
        }
        if(nums.at(i)+nums.at(i+1)==target){
            v.push_back(i);
            v.push_back((i+1));
        }

Comment: okay then is it possible to solve this question using recursion at all?

Comment: @NakulDeshmukh of course you get an error. Thats what I wrote. You are accessing the vector out of bounds. I suggested to use `at` to get an error rather than undefined behavior.

Comment: @NakulDeshmukh I do not understand your approach. Frankly it looks like you expected that adding recursion magically makes it better than brute force, but I dont see how that improves anything. I would sort the input, then use two iterators one starting from begin the other from end, then de-/increment them until you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation assumes that the two values must be found at adjacent indices in the vector.

Your code needs to consider the possibility that those two values are further apart. You can go for the brute-force idea to *search* for the second value in the remainder of the vector. So then your recursive function would become:

```
    void giveSolution(vector<int>& nums,int i,int target, vector<int> &v){
        if (i >= nums.size() - 1) { // Exit one step earlier as there is no more PAIR
            return;
        }
        // Find where the counter part of the current value is:
        auto it = find(nums.begin() + i + 1, nums.end(), target - nums[i]);
        if (it != nums.end()) { // Found it!
            v.push_back(i);
            v.push_back(it - nums.begin()); // ...at this index
        }
        else{
            giveSolution(nums, i+1, target, v);
        }
    }
```

Although recursion can at times be a very interesting option, it isn't here. This doesn't improve on the iterative brute force way to do it. It performs even worse, as it needs extra memory for the call stack, and for larger inputs it could run out of stack memory.

An efficient solution will make use of a hash map -- no recursion.

Answer (score -2):

What about a simple loop (sliding window approach) rather than a recursive algorithm?

Here' s my code:

```
class Solution {

    public:

        vector<int> giveSolution(vector<int>& nums, int target){

           vector<int> v;

           for(int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 1; i++){

               if(nums.at(i) + nums.at(i + 1) == target){

                   v.push_back(i);
                   v.push_back(i + 1);

               }

           }

           return v;

       }

};
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, it's missing a `;` after the class definition. If that's fixed it doesn't work, and generates some warnings. https://godbolt.org/z/hK4b9zxnE

Comment: Still won't find a solution unless the two values are sequential in the vector. https://godbolt.org/z/fh6nK7zb8